# Custom shell script in crontab

Tags: docker, cron, sh

I've a simple shell script that executes a docker-exec command inside a container. 
The script is located in `/var/www/mysite-nginx/nginx-reload.sh` and permissions of this file are `-rwxrwxr-x`

```
#!/bin/sh
docker exec -it mysite_nginx  nginx -s reload
```

If I execute this script directly from shell, it works. But if I add the script to my crontab with the following line, it doesn't work.

```
15 4 * * * /var/www/mysite-nginx/nginx-reload.sh
```

I suppose that cron doesn't execute the command, or **what is wrong?**

On `/var/log/syslog` I have:

```
Jul 23 15:30:01 arrubiu CRON[29511]: (sergej) CMD (/var/www/mysite-nginx/nginx-reload.sh)
```

[EDIT] Solved in this way: [docker exec is not working in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089033/docker-exec-is-not-working-in-cron)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that `docker` is not found. There are two ways around:

1. You enter the full paths of all application in your crontab script, you can find that out using e.g. `locate docker`, so that it looks something like

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/docker exec -it mysite_nginx  
/usr/bin/nginx -s reload
```

2. Alternatively, you can set the `$PATH` and other environment variables in the same way how they are set for a usual `sh`-script. To achieve that, first backup what is saved in `/etc/environment`, and then flush it with the currently available variables by executing:

```
cp /etc/environment > ~/my_etc_environment_backup
env >> /etc/environment
```

#### Related questions on SO

- [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/)