# docker exec command not working when called from batch file, that is called through a cron job

Tags: docker, cron

I'm trying to create a Teleporter backup of my pihole Docker container by running a cronjob every night that calls a backup.sh script.

If I do this manually, it works fine by issuing the following command. It puts the teleporter info in the /backup folder I present in my docker container. This allows me to copy the file to a different file share:

```
docker exec -it -w /backup pihole sh -c "pihole -a -t"
```

If I run the same command by running it inside a bash script, it works fine as well.

However, when I call that bash script through a cron job, this particular command does not get executed. I can see this, because no pi-hole-0423585190c3-teleporter_.tar.gz file exists after the nightly run, and my logfile doesn't show this file either. All other backup jobs in the backup.sh script work fine.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker exec is not working in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089033/docker-exec-is-not-working-in-cron)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in an [answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37089033).

Your docker exec command says it needs "pseudo terminal and runs in interactive mode" (-it flags) while cron doesn't attach to any TTYs.

Removed the "-it" and now is works